# Find the closure of this set (also, it the rest of my solution correct?)

Tags: general-topology

I have this problem practically solved, but I'm unsure about several things, so I'd appreciate if you could check it out and, if I made any mistakes, correct me. In particular, I have several doubts towards the end of the problem, at the time of finding a closure of a set. I put that problematic part under the horizontal line.

> Let $d_u$ be the usual, euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R^2}$, and
>   consider the distance
>   $d:\mathbb{R^2}\times\mathbb{R^2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined
>   by:
>   $$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=d_u((x_1,y_1),(0,0))+d_u((x_2,y_2),(0,0))$$

That is, the distance between two points is the sum of their euclidean distances to the origin. Defined like so for all points except if $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$, in which case the distance is $0$ by definition. Its easy to prove this is a valid definition of a distance.

Now, we can calculate how the open balls are:

$$B(p,r)=\{x\in\mathbb{R^2}:d(p,x)<r\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R^2}:[d_u(p,0)+d_u(x,0)]<r\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R^2}:d_u(x,0)<r-d_u(p,0)\}$$

So, if $r\leq d_u(p,0)\longrightarrow B(p,r)=\{p\}$
Because any other point would require to use the "longer" definition in the distance, in which case its clearly not possible to have a negative distance.

Now, if $r>d_u(p,0)\longrightarrow B(p,r)=B_u((0,0),r-d(p,0))\cup\{p\}$

That is, $\{p\}$ and a regular circle centered in the origin, which radius is the difference between $r$ and $d(p,0)$. So all this is pretty easy to deduct (although, if you find any mistake, please correct me).

---

Now, consider $A\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ an arbitrary set. Calculate its closure if $O\notin A$, and then if $O\in A$.

This is where its getting tricky. I'm using the characterization of the closure that says that, a point is in the closure of $A$ if and only if any open ball centered at the point intersects $A$.

By using this definition, and remembering that the open balls with this distance can be a single point, if we choose a small enough radius, its easy to determine that, a point $p$ that is not in $A$ won't be in the closure, since if its not in $A$, we can choose a radius $r$ such that $r\leq d_u(p,0)$, and then we will have found an open ball $B(p,r)$ that doesn't intersect $A$, because that ball is merely $\{p\}$, which is not in $A$. Hence we conclude that the set is closed since it equals its own closure.

Now, there are some tricky parts here that are making this a little complicated. If $p=O=(0,0)$, then that reasoning above doesn't work since there exist no open ball with $r\leq0$, hence the fact of it being in the closure or not would now depend on the points of the set $A$ itself. In the first case, if $O\in A$, there's no problem with this, and the above conclusion is valid.

If, on the other hand, $0\notin A$, then the closure would depend on whether the set is "scrapping" the origin or not. If its not, then we can still find an open ball centered in $O$ with small enough radius to not intersect $A$. But if $\inf\{d_u(x,O):\forall x\in A\}=0$, that is, the set is "scrapping" the origin, then the origin would indeed be in the closure of $A$.

As you can see this final part is kind of messy, so the reason I'm asking this question is to ask you whether all my reasoning is correct, opr if there are some parts that are just incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did find the ball centered at the origin, but, the line segment? Could you please develop that idea a little more? What I found is that an open ball centered at $\{p\}$ is either $\{p\}$, or a ball centered at the origin, union $\{p\}$.

Comment: Oh I see, no worries. Yeah I checked it is indeed a metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your entire reasoning is correct.

To put it simply, for every $p \neq 0$, $\{p\}$ is an open set and any open neighborhood of $O$ contains an open ball around $O$ in the *Euclidean metric*.

So, if $O \in A$, then $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A = \bigcup_{p \notin A} \{p\}$ which is open because each $\{p\}$ is open. Thus $A$ is closed.

On the other hand, if $O \notin A$, then the closure of $A$ is either $A$ or $A \cup \{O\}$, depending on whether or not there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $O$ (*the convergence may be checked only in the Euclidean metric*).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the simpler explanation Kiran ;) (couldn't reply earlier sorry).